# write an AND Condition in If statement in oracle

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, oracleforms

I am checking the text item in oracle form using if statement and an AND condition. Here is my code under the when button pressed. I need the correct syntax suggestion.

```
   BEGIN      
   IF     
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.COMPANY      AND
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.LAND_TYPE            AND    
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.DEED_NO              AND
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.LAND_TITLE           AND
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.LAND_SELLER_NAME     AND 
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.LAND_AREA            AND     
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.DEED_VALUE           AND  
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.ACTUAL_COAST         AND 
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.REGISTRATION_COAST   IS NOT NULL THEN

   commit_form;
   GO_BLOCK('RECORDVIEW');
   EXECUTE_QUERY();        
   GO_BLOCK('LAND_MANAGEMENT');
   create_record; 
   Clear_block(no_validate);
   FIRST_RECORD; 
   GO_ITEM('LAND_MANAGEMENT.COMPANY');
   END IF;   
   END;
```

Comment: Well, to begin with, a null check of x, y and z is not written `x AND y AND z IS NOT NULL`, it's `x IS NOT NULL AND y IS NOT NULL AND z IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The `and` operator is applied between conditionals, not between columns. You'd need to check every column for `null` dependently, and then apply `and`s between these checks:

```
IF     
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.COMPANY              IS NOT NULL AND
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.LAND_TYPE            IS NOT NULL AND    
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.DEED_NO              IS NOT NULL AND
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.LAND_TITLE           IS NOT NULL AND
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.LAND_SELLER_NAME     IS NOT NULL AND 
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.LAND_AREA            IS NOT NULL AND     
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.DEED_VALUE           IS NOT NULL AND  
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.ACTUAL_COAST         IS NOT NULL AND 
   :LAND_MANAGEMENT.REGISTRATION_COAST   IS NOT NULL THEN
```